# How can you add and multiply the values of a textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add the first two textboxes and then multiply the last one to that value and put that into a textbox but I am getting nowhere please help.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? do you mean textarea?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unclear.

You can give the three textboxes an id and create a variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<input id="firsttextbox"></input>
<input id="secondtextbox"></input>
<input id="thridtextbox"></input>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var firstTextbox = document.getElementById('firsttextbox'); 
var secondTextbox = document.getElementById('secondtextbox');
var thirdTextbox = document.getElementById('thirdtextbox');
```

Add the firstTextbox value and secondTextbox value and then multiply by third text box

```
function calculate() {
var sum = firstTextbox.value + secondTextbox.value;
var final = sum * thirdTextbox.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check each time there's a change in the document. you want to make sure that the user has entered a valid number in the first three text areas

```js
document.addEventListener("change", myScript);

function myScript(){

var texts = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

var cnt = 0;
for(let i = 0;i<3;i++){
   if(!isNaN(texts[i].value) && texts[i].value!='')cnt++;
   console.log(cnt);
}

if(cnt == 3){
texts[3].value = (parseFloat(texts[0].value)+parseFloat(texts[1].value))*parseFloat(texts[2].value);
}

}
```

```html
<textarea id='a1'></textarea>
<textarea id='a2'></textarea>
<textarea id='a3'></textarea>
<textarea id='a4'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<center>
<input type="text" id="t1" name="fname"><br>
<input type="text" id="t2" name="lname"><br>
<input type="text" id="t3" name="lname"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="script:
 var out=t1.value+t2.value*t3.value;
 alert(out);
 "value="Test It Out!!">
</center>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHD2JC3Q3N9T

Comment: FYI - I would take caution in using the <center> element, as it is now obsolete. You will want to use text-align instead.

Comment: I am aware of this but I fail to see any case where it would cause issues. Unless you could give a current example??

Comment: Per MDN: "This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."